# How do I replace an entire table in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, mysql, csv, phpmyadmin

We have a staff directory whose database lives in a table that I can see via phpMyAdmin but I don't know how to update it with new data. I have a csv file with all my data. Now what? Can someone explain the step-by-step process of what I should click on and/or what commands I need to type in order to update the table?

Answer (score 4):

Before you do anything, **back-up the entire database**. [Here are some instructions](http://vegdave.wordpress.com/2007/05/19/import-a-csv-file-to-mysql-via-phpmyadmin/) related to what you're trying to accomplish. Hope this helps.